# Error(28, 13):Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api

I would like to work with Google Maps.
My problem:

android-Studio 2.2, android-SDK 4.4, gradle:2.2.2, my OS: win-10

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
        compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "ir.amir.map"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    }
```

img:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on `Install Repository and sync project` option in the error. The SDK manager will install the missing repositories.

Comment: Are you running Android Studio from behind a proxy?

Comment: My SDK: http://uupload.ir/files/duq7_screenshot_(7).png   ////   http://uupload.ir/files/ypvy_screenshot_(8).png

Comment: Yes. proxy run.

Comment: Seems like android studio can't reach the servers. Configure android studio to work with the proxy. `Ctrl+Shift+A -> type "proxy"`. Enter the details and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added repositories to the *build.gradle* file which is stored in the root folder.

Try adding both `mavenCentral()` and `jcenter()`.

For example:

**build.gradle**:

```
// ...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// ...
```

Also you can simplify the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 21
```

Comment: @AmirKhoshnoud could you post your project (or just sample) to GitHub ?

Comment: No. I see Google Maps Education